# ¿Cómo tomar una sub-matriz de una lista de listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dada una cuadrícula de m x n llena de números no negativos, encuentre un camino desde la parte superior izquierda hasta la parte inferior derecha que minimice la suma de todos los números a lo largo de su ruta.

Nota: Solo puede moverse hacia abajo o hacia la derecha en cualquier momento.

Quiero saber como *moverse* en una lista de listas.

Por ejemplo con:

```
[
  [1,3,1],
  [1,5,1],
  [4,2,1]
]
```

Por ejemplo

```
class gridValued:

    def init(self, grid: List[List[int]]):
        self.grid=grid
        gridRight = new gridValued([grid[i][1:] for i in range(0,len (grid))])
        self.lengthRight = gridRight.value
        gridDown = new gridValued([grid[i][0:] for i in range(1,len (grid))])
```

Comment: En una lista de listas `l`, cuando accedes a `l[0]` verás su primer elemento, que es otra lista, y por tanto `l[0][0]` te dará el primer elemento de esa sublista. Es decir, de forma general, `l[i][j]` te permite acceder al elemento `j` de la fila `i`.

Answer (score 0):

En cada posición de la matriz tenemos dos caminos: derecha y abajo. Como excepción estaría la última fila y última columna, que sólo tiene un camino, y el último elemento de la esquina inferior derecha, que no tiene ningún camino.

Imagina que tenemos una función que genera los caminos, desde la posición `(i,j)` a la posición `(n,m)`:

```
def caminos(matriz: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
    n, m = len(matriz)-1, len(matriz[0])-1

    def aux(i: int, j: int) -> List[List[int]]:

        rutas = [[]] if (i,j) == (n,m) else (       # sin caminos
                  (aux(i+1, j) if i < n else []) +  # caminos abajo
                  (aux(i, j+1) if j < m else [])    # caminos derecha
                )

        return [[matriz[i][j]] + r for r in rutas]

    return aux(0, 0)
```

Para obtener la ruta mínima:

```
ruta_minima = min(caminos(matriz), key=sum)
```

A tener en cuenta que esta sería una solución por *fuerza bruta* calculando todas las rutas posibles. Hay otras estrategias mejores; pero sirve para dar una idea clar de cómo moverse por la matriz.